# Usage of the expression "My name has been... John Doe"

Tags: phrase-usage, present-perfect

The former radio host and current Youtuber, John "TotalBiscuit" Bain, often finishes his videos with the phrase *My name has been TotalBiscuit, thanks...*.

I'd never heard this expression before, and it sounds odd to me, as if it implied that his name changed after the show ended.

Is this just a very specific catchphrase? A common expression among radio hosts? Or used more commonly than that?

For instance, could I say it at the end of a scientific conference, such as "My name has been John Doe, and I presented you the results..."?

(As an example, this link takes to a Youtube video just before he says it: https://youtu.be/IydX8R2xxe4?t=51m51s)

Comment: Do not hesitate to correct my English, especially if it improves readability and conciseness.

Comment: I hope someone writes an answer naming this the Radio Show Perfect.

Comment: Radio DJs often welcome listeners at the top of a show with something like "I'm {name}. Welcome to Heavy Metal Madhouse" and then sign off with "This has been {DJ's name or show's name}. Until next week..."  I've never heard "My name has been {name}."

Comment: @TRomano Not arguing about your comment at all, but it's funny how following the same logic one might deem the host as dead at the end of show.

Comment: @kos: walking dead, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native English speaker, that sounds strange to me.  I have heard similar phrases where the host uses "has been," but usually in reference to the program, not himself.

e.g.

> I'm TotalBiscuit, and this has been *The Cynical Brit*

In this case, the tense makes sense, because the program is now over, so it makes sense to say, "This has been...".  It doesn't make sense to use "has been..." when referring to oneself.

If he signed off with

> This has been TotalBiscuit...

I could see that making sense, because it's really a short form of "This has been TotalBiscuit narrating this program," or something similar.  But "my name has been TotalBiscuit" makes no sense.

Comment: "...as if it implied...."  instead of "...as if it could imply..."  Please don't say "My name has been John Doe" especially after giving a scientific presentation.  At the end of the presentation, just say "Thank you.  Are there any questions?"

Comment: So, it's half-radioism, half-catchphrase. Thanks for confirming that one should never refer to himself/herself in the third person and consider his/her name as ephemeral.